# jquery ui switching classes function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, class

I have a bunch of thumbnail containers with a class and then two containers in them, like so:

```
<div id="color_dance" class="thumb">
    <img class="thumb_img" src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/tile_dance_color.jpg">
    <div class="thumb_info info_color_2"><p class="tile_info_1"> Space Series</p><p class="tile_info_2">Photoshop, Wacom Tablet</p></div>
</div>
```

When you click on it I'd like to switch the classes on all `.thumb_info` elements from `info_color_3` to `info_color_2` except the one clicked which does the opposite, switches the class from `info_color_2` to `info_color_3`.

This is the JS I came up with but it's not working and I'm not sure why.

```
$(".thumb").click(function() {
    $(".thumb_info").not(this).switchClass("info_color_3", "info_color_2", 300);
    $(this).find('.thumb_info').
    function() {
        $(this).switchClass("info_color_2", "info_color_3", 300);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `find('.thumb_info').function()`. You can call `.switchClass()` on the element returned by `.find()` though.

Try using the code like this:

```
$(".thumb").click(function() {
    $(".thumb_info").not(this).switchClass("info_color_3", "info_color_2", 300);

    $(this).find('.thumb_info').switchClass("info_color_2", "info_color_3", 300);
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sX4Wp/)

Comment: I updated the DEMO to better illustrate results on multiple sets of thumbs. It should do what you need but with a single thumb sample it was hard to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this function yet, but did you forget the "each" between "$(this).find('.thumb_info')." and "function"?

Try this:

```
$(".thumb").click(function() {
   $(".thumb_info").not(this).switchClass( "info_color_3", "info_color_2", 300 );
   $(this).find('.thumb_info').each(function() {
     $(this).switchClass( "info_color_2", "info_color_3", 300 );
   });
});
```